# how to know what version exists for a specific npm package?

Tags: npm, versioning

I am a noob. So I don't know where to find what is a valid version number.

For example, for code push, I only find this table in their readme:

```
React Native version(s) Supporting CodePush version(s)
<0.14   Unsupported
v0.14   v1.3 (introduced Android support)
v0.15-v0.18 v1.4-v1.6 (introduced iOS asset support)
v0.19-v0.28 v1.7-v1.17 (introduced Android asset support)
v0.29-v0.30 v1.13-v1.17 (RN refactored native hosting code)
v0.31-v0.33 v1.14.6-v1.17 (RN refactored native hosting code)
v0.34-v0.35 v1.15-v1.17 (RN refactored native hosting code)
v0.36-v0.39 v1.16-v1.17 (RN refactored resume handler)
v0.40-v0.42 v1.17 (RN refactored iOS header files)
v0.43-v0.44 v2.0+ (RN refactored uimanager dependencies)
v0.45+  TBD :) We work hard to respond to new RN releases, but they do occasionally break us. We will update this chart with each RN release, so that users can check to see what our "official" support is.
```

They mentioned v1.17, so I try

```
"react-native-code-push": "^1.17",
```

but then got error:

```
notarget No matching version found for react-native-code-push@^1.17
```

So from where do I know what previous versions number are valid for a package?

Comment: I like to use the [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) for that purpose, since the package info page on npmjs.com sucks for versions and `npm view` is a pain to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See last version of the package in the right column on [package page at npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-code-push):

[image]

#### To list all available versions run [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view):

```
npm view react-native-code-push versions
```

returns

```
[ '1.0.0-beta',
  '1.0.1-beta',
   …
  '2.0.3-beta',
  '2.1.0-beta' ]
```